# HttpClient doesn't get full website html source

Tags: c#, http, web-scraping, win-universal-app, html-agility-pack

I try to scrap offers from http://olx.pl/ site, I'm using HttpClient, problem is that site retrived from client is way diffrient and doesn't contain offers list like it is in source code accessed directly from browser. Any idea?
Here's my code:

```
  string url = "http://olx.pl/oferty/q-diablo/?search%5Bdescription%5D=1";
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Comment: Try change the user agent

Comment: Probably because that content is generated though javascript.

Comment: As Cyclone said many site use ajax and javascript to generate content, `HttpClient` doesnt run javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient` wont load content that is generated from javascript. Instead you can use WebView that will run js.  I ran both, `HttpClient` result had length of 235507 and `WebView` result lenght of 464476.

```
    WebView wv = new WebView();
    wv.NavigationCompleted += Wv_NavigationCompleted;
    wv.Navigate(new Uri(url));

    private async void Wv_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string wvresult = await sender.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, I've tried this solution and when I added WebView to xaml just to check if its loading, all shows correctly, but wvresult still contains only html without offers, its really strange, is there any other way to get WebView html source after loading?

Comment: How do you check the content? Sometimes happend to me, to not show all the html in the debug Watch. But when i save it to a file it contains it all.

Comment: Great Advice, thanks ! Yea, debug watch didn't show me all the html, but when I save it contains it all ! Thanks Again